# Find a piecewise algebraic formula for F(x) for all x

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Question as follows:

a)Let $f(x)=|x|$ and define $F(x)=\int_{-1}^xf$. Find a piecewise algebraic formula for $F(x)$ for all $x$. Where is $F$ continuous? Where is $F$ differentiable? Where does $F'(x)=f(x)$?

b) repeat for $ f(x) =
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill 1   \hfill & \text{ if $x < 0$} \\
      \hfill 2   \hfill & \text{ if $x \geq 0$} \\
      \end{cases}$

For part a) I have: $ F(x) =
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill \frac{1}{2}x^2   \hfill & \text{ if $x \leq 0$} \\
      \hfill \frac{1}{2}x^2   \hfill & \text{ if $x > 0$} \\
      \end{cases}$

F is continuous everywhere. F is differentiable everywhere except $x=0$. And that $F'(x)=f(x)$ only at $x=1$.

Am I correct? I think I'm on the right track but need some reassurance. Once I can figure out part a, I should be able to do part b.

Comment: Ah, typo. Meant to be $f(x)=|x|$. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Your formula for $F$ is incorrect, note that $F(0) = {1 \over 2}$. Solve for $x>0$ and $x<0$. $F$ is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following what you're saying. Should I just change the constraints of the function to reflect strict inequalities, $x < 0$ and $x > 0$?

Comment: No. Suppose $x<0$, then $f(x) = -x$ and you can compute an explicit formula for $F$. Now assume $x \ge 0$ and compute the formula. Then see if you can write the answer in a simple formula.

Comment: $x<0$, $f(x)=-x$, $F(x)=\int_{-1}^0-x dx$ = 1/2. For $x>0$, $f(x)=x$, $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}xdx=1/2x^2$. Is this what you mean? but for the first part, where $x<0$. doesn't $f(-x)=|x|=x$? Maybe I'm still missing something

Comment: If $x<0$, then $F(x) = {1 \over 2} (1-x^2)$. $F$ is not constant.

Comment: Okay, I changed the limits of integration... $x<0$, then $F(x)=\int_{-1}^x-xdx=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}x^2$. for $x>0$, then $F(x)=\int_{-1}^xxdx=\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: No. Try again. For $x\ge0$ you have $F(x) = {1 \over 2} (1+x^2)$. Note that $F(0) = {1 \over 2}$ (see my second comment above).

Comment: I'm guessing I should just change inequality to $x \geq 0$?, then $F(0)=\frac{1}{2}$...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by your last comment. The formulas must agree for $x \to 0$.

Comment: Before you editted comment before last you had $x > 0$ not $x \geq 0$...Can you give me a little more insight or explanation? I'm not sure how you got $F(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1+x^2)$

Comment: It is just integration, keeping in mind that $f(x) = -x$ for $x <0$ and $f(x) = x$ for $x>0$. I have added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\le 0$ then $F(x) = \int_{-1}^x -t dt = {1 \over 2} (1-x^2)$.

If $x\ge 0$ then $F(x) = F(0) + \int_0^x t dt = {1 \over 2} (1+x^2)$.

Combining gives $F(x) = {1 \over 2} (1+x|x|)$.

It is easy to see that $F$ is differentiable for $x \neq 0$ and
since $|F(x)-F(0)| \le |x|^2$, we see that $F$ is differentiable at $0$
with derivative $0$.

The fundamental theorem of calculus gives $F'(x) = f(x)$.